# Extracting latitude and longitude from ParseGeopoint in cloud code

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I hope and feel like this is a simple question, but can't figure it out.
Working with Parse Cloud code, I want to get the latitude and longitude from a Parse Geopoint.

```
  var loc = new Parse.GeoPoint(request.object.get('location'));
  console.log(loc);
```

console shows:

```
{"__type":"GeoPoint","latitude":55.012,"longitude":5.012}
```

How do I extract those values?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use JSON to read the object.
Jquery gives you this tool to read json data:

```
loc = $.parseJSON(loc);
```

That gives you a readable object.
then get the data By: loc.latitude AND loc.longitude

Comment: thanks for that, how do I load jquery in my cloudcode? `ReferenceError: $ is not defined`